# Eclipse "Run Configuration" showing only one Emulator instead of two (Android)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, run-configuration

I launched two emulators to send SMS on each other but whenever I go to "Run Configuration" to select emulators, it's showing only one running emulator.

Could you please tell me how to fix it?

Hope to hear from you soon.

Regards,

Parmanand

Comment: there may be some mismatch between the your minsdkversion,targetversion in the manifest and the emulator's android version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your AVD Target version. else Right click your project -> choose run as -> run configurations ->choose target -> In deployment target selection mode ->choose always prompt to pick device

it is used to finding compatible device.

Answer (score 2):

its eclipse problem. just restart it. until you didnt get it..

Comment: Ok thanks let me check...

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if both emulators are compatible with the minimum SDK version, i.e. `android:minSdkVersion` as you can see in your manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Comment: Ya I checked it is:                                                     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Comment: And I'm guessing both emulators are > 9.